# Problem with async/await method, can't go through all requests

Tags: swift, api, rest, async-await, func

I have a func, when I run the function it only goes through the first 2 requests and ignore last two requests(sessionId and getDetails)
If I remove validateUser, for example, then it doesn't ignor the sessionId

```
func requestAllAuthNetwork(username: String, password: String) async throws {
        Task {
            let token =  try await getToken()
            let validateUser =   try await validateUser(username: username, password: password, token: token.requestToken)
            let sessionId =  try await createSession(token: token.requestToken)
            let getDetails =  try await getDetails(sessionId.sessionID)
        }
    }
```

I try method "withThrowingTaskGroup" but the result was the same.
And some other method but nothing helped me.

```
func requestAllAuthNetwork(username: String, password: String) async throws {
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            let token = try await getToken()
            let validateUser =  try await validateUser(username: username, password: password, token: token.requestToken)

            try await group.next()

            group.addTask {

                let sessionId = try await self.createSession(token: token.requestToken)
                let getDetails = try await self.getDetails(sessionId.sessionID)
            }
            try await group.waitForAll()
        }
    }
```

Comment: All your code does is create some variables and throw them away. That's pointless.

Comment: The `Task {…}` in `requestAllAuthNetwork` should be removed. It is an `async` method, so `Task` is not needed. With it there, it will not await these calls. On top of that, you’re discarding away any errors that are thrown. Is the caller of `requestAllAuthNetwork` catching thrown errors and printing them?

Comment: By the way, in your second example, you are awaiting `group.next()` before adding any task, so it will not get to the line with the `addTask`. But this is not a good use case for task group, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring your errors.

```
func requestAllAuthNetwork(username: String, password: String) async throws {
        //Task { //Remove this
            let token =  try await getToken()
            let validateUser =   try await validateUser(username: username, password: password, token: token.requestToken) //If this throws an error
            let sessionId =  try await createSession(token: token.requestToken) //This line won't run, this is by design.
            let getDetails =  try await getDetails(sessionId.sessionID)
       // } //Remove this
    }
```

If the function is marked `async` your don't need `Task` and a floating `Task` like that is a perfect source for a race condition.

Then where you call `requestAllAuthNetwork(username: String, password: String)`

make sure you have a `do try catch`

```
do{
    try await requestAllAuthNetwork(username: "YourUsername", password:"Your password")
}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

I am pretty certain you will get an error in the console now.

When something `try` and then `throw` the operations below that line will not get executed. You have to resolve this for the rest of the lines to run.